How to Slice Multi Dimensional Array?
Dipping my toes into multi dimensional array slicing in Python and am hitting a wall of confusion with the following code
# Example 2D array
matrix = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]
# Basic slicing
result = matrix[0:2][1:2]
print(result)

So when I read this example with the following line: result = matrix[0:2][1:2]
I read this as result = matrix [rows][columns]
So to me I would think that this should return the first two rows of the matrix, and then the specified columns as per the slice [1:2]
So I would imagine it should return first the rows first -> [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]
Then after this it should take another slice with [1:2] so I would guess it should return [5]? Row 1 and up to the 2nd element?
When I run the code the following is the result
[[4,5,6]]
I am totally wrong so was wondering what am I missing?
I tried to google this kind of syntax where it has matrix[X:X][X:X] but I was not able to find out what is this called so if anyone can shed some light or point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

That's not a multidimensional array, it's a nested list, which doesn't support slicing like that. Did you mean to use NumPy?

With NumPy you'd do arr[0:2, 1:2], which returns [[2] [5]] (rows 0:2, columns 1:2). Setup: arr = np.array(matrix). See quickstart: Indexing, Slicing and Iterating under "Multidimensional arrays".

@wjandrea - Actually I am not into Numpy yet, this was given to me as a "basic example of slicing a multi-dimensional array". Sounds like I was given this mislabelled. The example you gave with NumPy makes a lot more sense to me and since you mentioned "nested list" this is making more sense to me. But how is the slicing not supported? I was trying to play around with it and it seems that "matrix[0:2][1:2]" almost acts like "matrix[slice_1][take slice_1 and make slice_2]. Is this how it works? Appreciate the help so far!

For "support", I mean, basically, "that syntax doesn't do what you seem to think it does". It makes one slice then makes another. It's like you cut a piece of pie then cut a smaller piece from that piece. Python lists don't support multidimensional slicing at all.

When get matrix[0:2] you receive 2 first elements of basic matrix with index 0 and 1:
[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]. Then you try slice[1:2] in getted before result you receive only 1 element with index 1 which equal [4, 5, 6]


@wjandrea - Thank you so much for the very basic explanation! Helps a ton!

@chilly8063 Oh, I didn't write this answer, KuLeMi did. I just fixed some typos :)

@KuLeMi - Appreciate the answer!
